# Chi-squared goodness-of-fit statistic if expected frequency is zero

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computing chi-square for large tables with some expected cell counts equal to zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7429/computing-chi-square-for-large-tables-with-some-expected-cell-counts-equal-to-ze)

The formula for chi-squared goodness-of-fit statistic is $\sum_i (O_i-E_i)^2/E_i$, which $O_i$ is observed frequency, $E_i$ is expected frequency. But, what can I do if $E_i$ is zero?

Comment: Is the expected frequency zero because of some pre-existing constraint, or is it only due to some marginal probabilities being zero by chance?

Comment: Will pre-existing constraint or marginal probabilities being zero by chance make a difference? I think in my case it is due to marginal probabilities being zero by chance.

Comment: Well, I'd say if you're trying to test whether a given frequency is zero, _any_ occurrence disproves that null hypothesis with infinite strength, no?

Comment: I recall essentially this same question coming up several months ago. (And, I believe the possible duplicate I've linked to below is not even the question I had in mind.) :)